# How to extract the keyword from a mono-alphabetic substitution cipher

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

I am a beginner to cryptography and I have the following question.

I know that to extract plaintext from a mono-alphabetic substitution cipher I can perform shifting the characters by $n$ times until I have the plaintext, or I can also use the frequency letter analysis.

However, by doing this I'm getting only the plaintext and not the keyword that been used. The answer might include creating a table with the alphabet linked to the corresponding letters used in ciphertext by following the frequency letter analysis but I'm not sure how this works.

Can someone explain to me how I will be able to get the keyword?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. I've given a hint on Stackoverflow. Now Show us what you tried up to now. Note: you can use $\LaTeX$/MathJax on this site.

Comment: i did not tried to do anything, i just want first to get the idea of that concept and then try to do anything on my own..

Comment: Well, the related questions tab on the right shows me a number of related questions with answers. Maybe start there.